# Django model keep field unchanged during update

Tags: django-models

My model is:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=False)
```

I would like `created_at` and `created_by` to stay **unchanged** upon update of the object. `created_at` works that way because of `auto_now_add=True` but I can't find a similar option for other model fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with serializers is to override the `update()` function and refrain from updating the `created_at` and `created_by` fields.

For example in, lets say, `serilalizers.py`:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=14)

    # Other functions like create() ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```